# MySQL from many queries to one?

Tags: mysql

I have many queries and want to combine them into one query cause it loads to long :/

First I select items with opened = 0 limit by 1 and update that to opened = 1 in the second query.

Then I select the count of cases and the sum of item_price of all opened 1 from the trade_id in the 3rd query.

In the 4th i get the count of all cases from that trade_id not only the opened = 1 and the last query i select * from cases where opened = 1 and trade_id = trade_id ordered by the item_price DESC

That's to many queries, and I want them into one query.

But there are `SELECT` queries and also update query in one? Is that working?

Here are my queries:

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cases 
WHERE opened = 0 
  AND trade_id = ' + pool.escape(tradeid) + ' 
ORDER BY caseid 
LIMIT 1
```

Query #2:

```
UPDATE cases 
SET opened = 1, openedtime = ' +time() + ' 
WHERE case_id = ' + pool.escape(row[0].case_id)
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS cases, SUM(`item_price`) AS preturile 
FROM 
    cases 
WHERE 
    opened = 1 
    AND trade_id = ' + pool.escape(tradeid)
```

Query #4:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS casessum 
FROM 
    cases 
WHERE 
    trade_id = ' + pool.escape(tradeid)
```

Query #5:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cases 
WHERE opened = 1 
  AND trade_id = ' + pool.escape(tradeid) + ' 
ORDER BY item_price DESC
```

It would be very nice if someone can help me to build that queries into one. 
I searched for a much but never find something with that many queries :/

Comment: You cannot combine a select that returns a resultset and an update into one query.

Comment: Hm okay... can you give me an example how to make that faster? It needs like a second for all that querys... is there a way to combine them or something

Comment: Unless you already have it, try an index on `cases (trade_id, opened)`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? :/

Comment: What example? Index `(trade_id, opened)` of `cases` is already as specific as possible.